# How to portray responsibilities that are unusual for my title on my resume?

Tags: resume, linkedin, job-description

To put it very briefly - I am a **vendor relationship manager** working with software/IT service providers, but our company decided that I and others like me should be heavily involved in areas of IT solutions and programming so that we are more proficient and informed when making decisions. Coming from a purely business background, this is unusual for my role.

I essentially spent a very significant amount of my time in this role (more than 50%) on projects that normally a junior database or business analyst would perform (according to what I heard from other companies).

When applying for other jobs, how can I portray this...

a. if the vacancy is purely in the same business area of my job description?

b. if the vacancy is more technically oriented like business analyst or solutions architect?

Answer (score 4):

Many companies really want people that are deep in the technology  but can also understand the business.  That is pretty rare.

I would be sure to include that information in your summary (resume and online profiles) "equally skilled in Vendor Management as well as Database Business Analysis functions......"

I agree with including it in the cover letter - but some/many recruiters don't read them (sorry but true - they are a 2nd file in our systems), so be sure to blend that information in the resume itself.  Also be sure to add the appropriate tools/technologies/keyword associated with the technical work that you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

### Resume/LinkedIn

> When applying for other jobs, how can I portray this...

On your resume/LinkedIn, list the responsibilities you did under your job title. You could also add the position you were also doing in parenthesis.

- Vendor Relationship Manager (Business Analyst)

  - VRM item 1
  - BA Analyst item 1
  - VRM item 2
  - BA Analyst item 2

If you are applying for a more tech heavy position simply put more emphasis on the tech responsibilities you had. Vice versa for the more business side.

I recommend having a "master" resume where you list everything and then remove the lower importance ones as needed for each position you apply to.

### Cover Letter

A cover letter is a perfect place to add something like:

- "My responsibilities are official vendor relationship management, however I also do work more closely affiliated with business analyst responsibilities such as A, B, C."

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes companies/managers give more responsibilities to prepare them for a subsequent role - maybe what your company envisages is a type of hybrid, more tech savvy role.

I think it wouldn't be wrong to include some sort of hybrid specification as part of your job title on the resume.

Example:
Vendor Relationship Manager & Business Analyst